# Diagonalizing matrices of linear forms of indeterminates

Tags: linear-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, oa.operator-algebras

Let $B$ be a matrix with elements as linear forms of indeterminates. Is there a proper diagonalization procedure for such matrices like those of matrices with real and complex entries?

Comment: What do you mean by "diagonalization procedure" ? 

Comment: Say we have a non-singular matrix over complex numbers with unequal eigenvalues, then we can diagonalize such matrices. Can we have a procedure for these matrices as well? I have a bottleneck in a proof.

Comment: Couldn't $B$ be considered as matrix over a function field $k(x_i\mid i \in I)$ ? 

Comment:  Sure but I believe $k[x_{i}|i∈I]$  is more correct since I have only linear forms.

Comment: Over the function field diagonalization works as over every field. But there is in general no $X \in GL_n(k[x_i|i \in I])$ such that $X^{-1}BX$ is diagonal. As an example take $$B = \begin{pmatrix}x_1 & x_2 \\ x_1 & x_2\end{pmatrix}$$. In this case $X$ is (up to permutation of columns) $$X = \begin{pmatrix}x_2f & g \\ -x_1f & g\end{pmatrix}$$ with polynomials $f,g$. Thus $\det(X) = (x_2 - x_1)fg \notin k[x_i]^\times = k$. // But this is nothing special for linear forms, it's typical for matrices over integral domains. 

Comment: As a precaution I should add to the first sentence in the comment ahead that matrices over fields are usually not diagonalizable and the Jordan form only exists if the characteristic polynomial decomposes into linear factors. 

Comment: May I also add that there exist a simple criterion to check whether the digonalization is possible at all:  http://arxiv.org/abs/1305.2256